# How to pass document type parameter to xslt using saxon?

Tags: c#, xslt-2.0, saxon

For sending atomic data types will use like

```
transformer.SetParameter(new QName("", "", customXml), new XdmAtomicValue("true"));
```

how to pass a XML/Node as a param to XSLT from C# ?

Can you please help me

followed your code it's working fine but i am getting only text inside the xml(what i am passing in parameter) but not Nodes

XSLT :

```
  <xsl:param name="look-up" as="document-node()"/>
  <xsl:template match="xpp:document">           
  <w:document xml:space="preserve"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$look-up"/>
  </w:document>
  </xsl:template>
```

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <document version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/xpp">
    //some tags 
</document>
```

passing parameter (xml)

```
 <Job>
   </id>
 </Job>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the `Processor` object to construct an `XdmNode`, see the documentation which says:

> The Processor provides a method NewDocumentBuilder which, as the name
>   implies, returns a DocumentBuilder. This may be used to construct a
>   document (specifically, an XdmNode) from a variety of sources. The
>   input can come from raw lexical XML by specifying a Stream or a Uri,
>   or it may come from a DOM document built using the Microsoft XML
>   parser by specifying an XmlNode, or it may be supplied
>   programmatically by nominating an XmlReader.

Then you can pass in the `XdmNode` to the `SetParameter` method http://saxonica.com/documentation/html/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltTransformer.html#SetParameter%28Saxon.Api.QName,Saxon.Api.XdmValue%29 as `XdmValue` is a base class of `XdmNode` (XmlValue -> XdmItem -> XdmNode).

Here is an example that works for me with Saxon 9.5 HE on .NET:

```
        Processor proc = new Processor();

        DocumentBuilder db = proc.NewDocumentBuilder();

        XsltTransformer trans;
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("../../XSLTFile1.xslt"))
        {
            trans = proc.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(xr).Load();
        }

        XdmNode input, lookup;

        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("../../XMLFile1.xml"))
        {
            input = db.Build(xr);
        }

        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("../../XMLFile2.xml"))
        {
            lookup = db.Build(xr);
        }

        trans.InitialContextNode = input;

        trans.SetParameter(new QName("lookup-doc"), lookup);

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
        {
            trans.Run(new TextWriterDestination(xw));
        }
```

The XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:param name="lookup-doc"/>

  <xsl:key name="map" match="map" use="key"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('map', ., $lookup-doc)/value"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the XML documents are

```
<root>
  <item>foo</item>
</root>
```

and

```
<root>
  <map>
    <key>foo</key>
    <value>bar</value>
  </map>
</root>
```

the resulting output is

```
<root>
  <item>bar</item>
</root>
```

Comment: getting this exception :System ID: D:\Testservice\Install_Test\DOCX_XSLT\CustomXML.xsl
Scenario: CustomXML1
XML file: C:\Users\velagasx\Desktop\divxml.xml
XSL file: D:\Testservice\Install_Test\DOCX_XSLT\xml2docx.xsl
Engine name: Saxon-HE 9.4.0.6
Severity: fatal
Description: XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic
Start location: 11:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPTY0019

Comment: i am passing param 
 XdmNode input; 
//code
transformer.SetParameter(new QName("", "", responsedetails), input) where input is

Comment: Please edit your question with details so that we can reproduce the problem, I have tried my suggestions with Saxon 9.5 and I have not had any problems getting the parameter passed in and recognized.

Comment: HI Martin Honnon, 
Thanks for reply. 
Please find the above edited question . please help me

Comment: It's working Now 
changed to <xsl:copy-of select="$look-up"/>