# Passing and parsing XML as a parameter to XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to figure out how to pass XML into a XSLT document and parse it as you would on any node.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="xmlparam"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="node()"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:value-of select="$xmlparam/coll"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xmlparam:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<coll>
    <title>Test</title>
    <text>Some text</text>
</coll>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<coll>
    Root doc
</coll>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    Root doc

XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic
```

Does anyone know how to parse XML passed in as a parameter to XSLT?  Due to certain restraints, I cannot read in a file, it needs to be a parameter.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767097/xslt-reading-a-param-thats-an-xml-document-passed-as-a-string/23768464#23768464

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use, how/where do you pass in the parameter? It all depends on the XSLT processor you use and the API it provides to parse XML and to pass in a parameter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077219/how-to-pass-document-type-parameter-to-xslt-using-saxon/24077951#24077951 for a sample with the .NET version of Saxon 9 for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your XML input to be parsed by the style sheet by using the document function, e.g. like (from memory, so maybe not completely accurate)

```
<xsl:variable name="myData" select="document('myData')"/>
```

AND registering a custom URIResolver with the with your Transformer. This custom URIResolver will get `"myData"` as value of the parameter `href` of its `resolve` method and could then obtain the content of the document from e.g. a `String`. This would give you roughly the same flexibility as adding the content as a parameter.

Code sketch (assuming the obvious implementation of MyURIResolver):

```
Transformer myTransformer = getMyTransformer();
String myXmlDocument = getMyXmlDocumetAsString();
URIResolver myURIResolver = new MyURIResolver();
myURIResolver.put("myData", myXmlDocument);
myTransformer.setURIResolver(myURIResolver);
myTransformer.transform(source, result);
```